# PostgreSQL partition using TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, database-partitioning

I want to use typeorm with partition in PostgreSQL.
How can i do that?
Just use raw query for create database?
In my case, our data really big. Especially one table which called annotation is larger than 100M rows in there.

So, I think partiton must do it for our project
How can i  partition in nestjs-typeorm environment?
I found that TypeORM not support that kind of partitioning

Comment: What problem do you think partitioning would solve?

Answer (score 1):

So I found this [relevant issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1940) for you and look at this comment by pleerock

> partition is your table internal functionality and does not affect object relational model anyhow. And its a bit specific so executing a raw query in a migration lets say sounds quite okay there. Don't you think its enough to make typeorm and partitions work?

Also, if by any chance you are looking to select from a partitioned table and you need to retrieve data from specific partition, then TypeORM does not support that.

You can use raw query in this case, although Postgres does optimizations by itself.

Comment: TypeORM does not need to support anything regarding partitioning. If the partitions are defined properly then the Postgres query optimizer will take care of that (_if_ the partition key is part of the WHERE clause).